# how to access items in this stdClass Object that is return from php/soap?

Tags: php, soap, stdclass

i am using osticket api and had developed this function to integrate osticket into my web application:

```
    function ReadTicket($ticketID)
    {
     $osticket = new SoapClient('url');

    $args = array(

        'username'        => 'someuser',

        'password'        => 'some pass',

        'ticketID'        => 1234); 

    try {
        $result = $osticket->__call('ostTicket.getMessages',$args);



      print_r( $result  );    





}

catch (SoapFault $e) {

    throw $e;

} 
}
```

and here is the result from print_r command:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [question] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 80 [created] => 2012-11-25T14:48:29-06:00 [name] => name [message] => body ) [answers] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 80 [created] => 2012-11-30T23:52:48-06:00 [name] => Admin Admin [message] => testttttttttt ) ) )` )

how to access the result and print out only id and message?

here is a reference to the soap call
http://www.cyberde.nl/software-en-US/osticket-soap-mod/ostticket-getmessages/

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result[0]['answer'] as $ans)//one ore more answers
 echo $ans['id']." '".$ans['message']."'<br/>";
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like `$result[0]->question->id` or for multiple results

```php
foreach($result as $r){
  echo $r->question->id;
  foreach($r->answers as $answer){
    echo $answer->id;
  }
}
```